# Hide/Unhide controls on main form based on control's tag using on current event in continuous sub form

Tags: vba, ms-access

First post. Can you please advise how to fix this error in my code. I hope I ask this question correctly. I have a main form with a continuous sub form. There is a control in the sub form for item type called lngIteTypFK. I am trying to use the sub forms on current event to make unbound controls on the main form hidden or visible based on the main form controls tag. Visible if the value of the tag equals the value of the item type. I am getting the error "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Visible" when I try to run the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim frm As Form
Dim ctl As Control
Dim varlngIteTypFK As Long

Set frm = Forms!frmQot

varlngIteTypFK = Me.lngIteTypFK

For Each ctl In frm

    Select Case ctl.Tag
        Case Is = 0
            ctl.Visible = True 'error happens here
        Case Is = 1
            ctl.Visible = False
        Case Is = varlngIteTypFK
            ctl.Visible = True
        Case Else
            ctl.Visible = False
    End Select

Next ctl

ExitError:
     Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
     MsgBox Err.Description
     Resume ExitError
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried this structure. I do not get error.

Comment: Thank you for trying. This really has me stumped.

Comment: I have just tried this code in a fresh database with just the forms and the code and it worked perfectly. There is something else going on here. I will report back if I find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. The parent form has empty cells on it. For some reason the error is caused by these empty cells when looping through the controls. I have added a line to test if the control is a label, text box or combo box. This solved the problem as follows:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Current()
'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim frm As Form
Dim ctl As Control
Dim varlngIteTypFK As Long

Set frm = Forms!frmQot

varlngIteTypFK = Me.lngIteTypFK

For Each ctl In frm
    If ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Or ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acLabel Then 'added this line
        Select Case ctl.Tag
            Case Is = 0
                ctl.Visible = True
            Case Is = 1
                ctl.Visible = False
            Case Is = varlngIteTypFK
                ctl.Visible = True
            Case Else
                ctl.Visible = False
        End Select
    End If
Next ctl

ExitError:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitError
End Sub
```